# I am trying to deploy LDAPLoginModule in Karaf but no success

Tags: ldap, realm, apache-karaf, jaas

I am trying to deploy the following file in Karaf but I am unable to do so with any success
I have placed the blueprint XML file in deploy folder of Karaf. Do I need to run any **feature:install** or **bundle:install** command explicitly for this file to replace the default Karaf realm

**Below is my XML:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:jaas="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/jaas/v1.1.0">

    <jaas:config name="karaf" rank="2">
        <jaas:module className="org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.ldap.LDAPLoginModule"
            flags="required">
            initialContextFactory=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
            connection.username=admin
            connection.password=xxxxxxx
            connection.protocol=
            connection.url=ldap://activedirectory_host:389
            user.base.dn=ou=Users,ou=there,DC=local
            user.filter=(sAMAccountName=%u)
            user.search.subtree=true
            role.base.dn=ou=Groups,ou=there,DC=local
            role.name.attribute=cn
            role.filter=(member=%fqdn)
            role.search.subtree=true
            authentication=simple
        </jaas:module>
    </jaas:config>
</blueprint>
```

Comment: Any logs? I have similar configuration, the only difference is that `connection.username` is in LDAP format (`cn=admin,dc=...,dc=...`).

Comment: Hi @GrzegorzGrzybek Thanks for reaching out. I placed this in deploy folder but it is not registering. Do I have to install it from Karaf console?

Comment: Maybe you don't have `deployer` feature installed? It's responsible for installing XML files from `deploy/` directory. Or indeed, you can install this file using `install -s blueprint:file:///path/to/file.xml`.